# Syncing Development Site with Production Site

Tags: 8, deployment

I recently built my first Drupal 8 site. I've updated the production site since it's been launched, and I wanted to sync it with the development site before I create another content type.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to sync the database and the whole complete Drupal folder. Every single file except for `.htaccess` and `settings.php` as they may be different in every environment.

---

And from now on you start to do things just the other way around.

`git init` a Git repo on your local machine. Then you do every update, every UI change, every site building task on your local machine first.

When you are done locally you do `drush cex` to export the new configuration into YAML files. I think you can do that from the UI as well.

Then you deploy (upload) these YAML files to your live site and start the configuration import, `drush cim` or UI.

Similar with updating Drupal. Wether Composer or manually, you do that on your local machine first. Then deploy the resulting `composer.lock` file or the updated files to your live site and start the database updates once again, `drush updb` or from the UI.

---

From now and then you get a database dump from your live site and import that locally. Maybe you download or `rsync` the whole `sites/default/files` folder to your local machine as well. This one and your `settings.php` are going to be ignored from Git.

That's how things are supposed to go. File changes always upstream, database dumps downstream.

---

After you've set up Git correctly you may start to use Git Flow. Which expects you to work in different Git branches, `master` and `develop`. And `feature/*` branches when developing new features locally.

Basically when you're done with a feature you merge the feature branch into the `develop` branch and push the changes to your Dev server. Once in a while you start a new `release` where the `develop` branch gets merged into the `master` branch. And the `master` branch would be the one that pushes stuff to the Live server.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. What would I need to put in my repo? I'm running a Bootstrap subtheme. Should I just put the subtheme folder in the repo?

Comment: @TomNguyen – No you put everything in that repo that lets you restart your whole (Drupal) project from the current state. Except for stuff that's environment-specific or holds sensitive information like `settings.php` and/or `.htaccess`. And you also ignore the complete `sites/default/files` folder. As that similar to the database holds user-generated content.